# Distance between two cities measured on a straight line

Tags: expressions

How can I express a thought of a distance between two cities measured as a length of a line segment connecting them on a map, as opposite to distance of the two cities measured as length of a road connecting them?

a) in a straight line

b) as the crow flies

c) length of beeline

context: Distance between Paris and Rome is 1104 km measured in a straight line.

Comment: Are you taking into account the curvature of the Earth?

Comment: Good question. Let's consider both these two cases and let's find out.

Comment: Nice use of 2nd person plural :) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601440/when-is-it-acceptable-to-address-someone-else-in-the-first-person-as-in-the-cla/601442#601442

Comment: Geodetic distance is the default metric for any distance measurement on the earth's surface. You don't need any extra terms for this. If you want the driving distance between two cities, you need to say driving distance. In cities with a regular  block layout, the driving distance is predictable based on addresses; and this is the basis of the "taxi cab metric".

Answer (score 5):

**"As the crow flies"** works here. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_the_crow_flies) defines it as:

> In a straight line distance between two locations, as opposed to the road distance or over land distance.

From that definition, "in a straight line" would also work. However, strictly speaking the distance between two points over Earth's surface is *not* a line but a geodesic (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)), so I would take "in a straight line" to be (if we are being *extremely* pedantic) misleading. The length of the line segment between two points on a map depends entirely on the map projection in use, and this itself differs from the straight-line distance between two points, since such a line could go beneath the Earth's surface.

These distinctions are particularly important over long distances where such discrepancies become larger. You usually care about the geodesic distance, since that determines travel time. "As the crow flies" presumably refers to geodesic distances, since it is based on the idea that a crow would take the shortest route over Earth's surface.

The word "beeline" is used primarily in the idiom "make a beeline for"; per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beeline), "beeline" refers to a straight, direct course. But it does not appear to refer unambiguously to the geodesic distance.

Comment: It seems to me that the crow’s straight line, being in the air, *is* a straight line and shorter than the ant’s surface-curving straight line.

Comment: Consider a metaphorical crow going from Argentina to China. If it flew in a straight line in Euclidean space, it would go through the Earth's core. If it followed a straight line on a typical map, meanwhile, it would have to go *east,* around almost the entire globe, instead of going west over the Pacific. (This gets even more complicated when you consider the math of map projections.)

Comment: Since the crow can also move up and down, it may not exactly be a geodesic on the Earth's surface, but it's quite close. (Of course, "as the crow flies" does typically ignore, say, tall buildings or local topography that crows must fly around.)

Comment: We can get the crow a Pacific-centered map and send it westward. In any case, the metaphorical crow flies a Euclidean straight line — without concern for obstacles, curvatures, or altitude adjustments.

Comment: Again, not unless it can go through the Earth's core. The Euclidean straight line from Argentina to China goes down through the Earth. The crow's flight doesn't even approximate that; it approximates a geodesic going over the Earth's surface, since that is the shortest path along the surface. (We assume the crow stays at a roughly constant altitude above sea level, as you note. You could say that the crow is flying along a geodesic of an imaginary ellipsoid that extends to X meters above sea level, since that is the shortest path of constant altitude.)